# Dropdownlist adding list items

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, list, drop-down-menu

I have added some data from the local database to a List, and now I need to show the values this List has inside a dropdownlist. The List contains the following data:

- Java
- .net
- JavaScript
- Ruby
- Python

Method:

```
public List<string> DisplayTopicNames()
{


    // declare the connection string 
    string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

    // Initialise the connection 
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);
    //Query
    string queryStr = "SELECT TopicName FROM Topics";
    // Create a command object 
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, myConn);
    // Open the connection 
    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    // Execute the command 
    OleDbDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();


    // Extract the results 
   List<string> topicNames = new List<string>();

    while (myDataReader.Read())
    {
        topicNames.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }

    // close the connection 
    myCommand.Connection.Close();
    return topicNames;
}
```

}

When I return the above method on its own it works fine and all the values are there but When I use the following code to add this List to the dropdownlist it only shows "j" "a" "v" "a" which is very strange.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = dt.DisplayTopicNames(); 
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
topicNames.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

try this:

```
topicNames.Add(myDataReader["TopicName"].ToString());
```